# React re-rendering todo array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

Hey y'all I'm attempting to give a go at a todo app on my own with minimal tutorial help so I can work things through. I'm using react hooks and am a little confused on why after pushing a new todo to my array it does not re-render. Would I need useEffect? I suspect it might have something to do with arrays being immutable? Also, if you check the console in the codesandbox I get weird behavior where if you click add todo and leave the input the same it will add multiple todos to the array, however when you type in a different input it erases them all and just replaces it with the current value you put in. Any help with these issues would be great so I can keep working!

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-einstein-2n121?file=/src/interface.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the todos in state for the component to rerender,

Try this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-goldberg-t3kn3?file=/src/interface.js

Comment: Ohh yea, that is perfect. Still learning the ins and outs of react and forgot that part about state re-rendering when set. Thanks! :)